# Java Optional Get if Present

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a java optional object that I only want to get if it's present. The obvious code here is:

```
JsonGenerator gen;
if(value.isPresent()) {
    gen.writeObject(value.get());
}
```

But I want to see if I can steamline that to 1 line with the `ifPresent` method. I don't want it to write at all if it's not present. I tried something like this:

```
gen.writeObject(value.ifPresent(a -> a));
```

But that clearly didn't work. Is there any way to do what I want? Everything I've researched online only shows the use of `ifPresent` with a method call for the predicate.

**Edit 1:**
I tried Tunaki's solution but I am getting the following error:

```
Error:(25, 46) java: incompatible thrown types java.io.IOException in method reference
```

Here's my entire block of code:

```
public class FooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        value.getFooA().ifPresent(gen::writeObject);
    }
}
```

I even tried:

```
public class FooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Foo value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        try {
            value.getContactInfo().ifPresent(gen::writeObject);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can invoke `gen.writeObject` as a consumer of your object in `ifPresent`:

```
value.ifPresent(gen::writeObject);
```

This will invoke the method only if the `Optional` isn't empty.

In your example, the method `writeObject` throws the checked exception `IOException`; you will need to catch it and either throw a runtime exception instead (like the new [`UncheckedIOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html), which complicates a little the code) or do something else (like log it):

```
value.ifPresent(v -> {
    try {
        gen.writeObject(v);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution and got an error, I made an edit to my post.

Comment: @Richard Ha yes if your method throws a checked exception, you need to catch it and rethrow an unchecked one (or do something else).